# bootstrap modal auto scroll to bottom when softkeyboard appear in mobile

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal

There is a bootstrap modal, in which there are some input fields when I try to open in mobile the and click on input filed and soft keyboard appear the modal itself get auto scrolled to the bottom